# Visual Studio 2010: create your own layout for listview - [Render Template]

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, asp.net-webcontrol

Ok i need write less code. How i can create my own Layout in the ListView configuration wizard?

[image]

I want add my custom Layout in "Select a Layout" box. It's possibile? How i can? 
Thanks

Comment: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/29/working-with-the-listview.aspx